# Wildfly Maven Plugin not updating config

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8, wildfly-maven-plugin

We used to be able to update our Wildfly app server configuration (standalone-full-ha.xml) using wildfly-maven-plugin 1.0.2.Final. It stopped working when we switched to version 1.2.2.Final. We're still on Wildfy 8.2.1.  I had to upgrade the plugin because of [deployment problems over SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708206/wildfly-maven-plugin-deployment-over-ssl-works-once-then-connection-error).

Here's the subproject pom.xml

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-${project.artifactId}</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute-commands</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <execute-commands>
                                    <scripts>
                                        <script>${basedir}/processed/scripts/add-${project.artifactId}.cli</script>
                                    </scripts>
                                </execute-commands>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
...
```

I executed:

```
 > mvn package -e -P nonclustered
...
        [INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:1.2.2.Final:execute-commands (add-jboss-security) @ jboss-security ---
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Total time: 6.814 s
        [INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-11T14:49:03-04:00
        [INFO] Final Memory: 22M/365M
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The build succeeds, but the config doesn't update. No errors. I tried searching online to find out which wildfly-maven-plugin versions work with which Wildfly app server version but I can't find any information.

Comment: That should still work. You might want to file an issue at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFMP if it's not working. That should connect to the server running the localhost and execute the CLI script.

Comment: done https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFMP-102